# How to sort products in a category by their average rating in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to sort products in a certain category by their product rating but it doesn't work. I think it sorts by newly added. Much appreciate the help :D

```
$category = get_queried_object();
            
            $top_products = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_key',
                'meta_key' => '_wc_average_rating',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $category->term_id, /*category name*/
                        'operator' => 'IN',
                        )
                    )
                ));
```